# Incrementing object id automatically JS constructor (static method and variable)

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, closures, ecmascript-5

I am newbie in JavaScript, I have an idea, to create class (function), I know how it works in JS (prototypes and so on), but I need to do something like incrementing Id in databases.

My idea is to create static method, I think closure will suit great here and whenever new object is created it should return incremented id.

I don't know what is the right way to implement this, or maybe this is bad practice.

Please provide simple example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closure is a good idea:

```
var MyClass = (function() {
  var nextId = 1;

   return function MyClass(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.id = nextId++;
   }
})();

var obj1 = new MyClass('joe'); //{name: "joe", id: 1}
var obj2 = new MyClass('doe'); //{name: "doe", id: 2}
```

Or, if you want some more flexible solution you can create simple factory:

```
function MyObjectFactory(initialId) {
  this.nextId = initialId || 1;
}

MyObjectFactory.prototype.createObject = function(name) {
  return {name: name, id: this.nextId++}
}

var myFactory = new MyObjectFactory(9);
var obj1 = myFactory.createObject('joe'); //{name: 'joe', id: 9}
var obj2 = myFactory.createObject('doe'); //{name: 'doe', id: 10}
```

```

Comment: Thank you for answer !!! Can you please explain first example, if I need to put some logic checking arguments count of constructor for example like this `var Product = function Product() {
    this.name = "";
    this.amount = "";
    this.price = "";
    this.picture = "";
    if (arguments.length == 4) {
        this.name = arguments[0];
        this.amount = arguments[1];
        this.price = arguments[2];
        this.picture = arguments[3];
    }
};`

Where should I put this logic inside returned function ?

Answer (score 0):

Since node is single threaded this should be easy and relatively safe to do.

I think you could accomplish this by creating a global variable

`global.counter = 0`

Then on construction your class could increment it, or increment and grab the value if you need to keep reference to the value when the class was created.

```
function YourClass() {
   global.counter++;
}
var yc = new YourClass(); // global.counter 1
var yc2 = new YourClass(); // global.counter 2
```

Comment: is there any way to do this function static for object (prototype) for example when constructor is called execute this method to get unique id of object ? Using closure for example

Comment: @Michael Prokopowicz's answer is significantly cleaner

Comment: An example using static function written in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41916397/3150964)

Comment: Would the global value persist?