# Call all methods in a class when an instance is created

Tags: javascript, iife

Let's say I have a class that looks like this

```
class Foo {
  bar() {
    console.log('bar');
  }

  baz() {
    console.log('baz');
  }

  // other methods...
}
```

and I want all of its methods to be unconditionally called whenever a new instance is created. How would I go about that?

I'm currently doing it by calling each method in the class `constructor` method

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar();
    this.baz();
    // other methods
  }

  bar() {
    console.log('bar');
  }

  baz() {
    console.log('baz');
  }

  // other methods...
}
```

here's a snippet of that

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar();
    this.baz();
    // other methods
  }

  bar() {
    console.log('bar');
  }

  baz() {
    console.log('baz');
  }

  // other methods...
}

new Foo();
```

Is there a better way to do this?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55501954/11228357) seems to be the closest to what I want to achieve. It works by ditching class methods and using IIFEs in `classProperties` instead.

So something like this

```js
class Foo {
  bar = (() => {
    console.log('bar');
  })()

  baz = (() => {
    console.log('baz');
  })()
}

new Foo();
```

and it works well on Chrome but the majority of other browsers [don't yet have support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Browser_compatibility) for `classProperties` since they were added in ES9

My question is:

If I have a class with a number of methods in it, can I call all of them whenever a new instance of that class is created without having to call each individual method in the `constructor` method of that class?

In the context of this question, you can completely ignore the need to pass parameters to the methods. I don't need to pass any parameters to any of the class methods.

Comment: Just use a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oCMwCdoF5oAKIgSgID4V0Nph4A7CeEAUwDoR4BzIgcmw4-pANw0AvqTKoa2AF4FiZStVp1GzNpx795wsRknTxMhqwDucRGRFA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.8.4&externalPlugins=), the last example you posted will work everywhere (tested in IE11 successfully)

Comment: If the properties with iifes example meets your requirements in terms of behavior, it really calls into question why you're using a class in the first place

Answer (score 1):

If the order in which you call the methods is not important, you can iterate dynamically over the properties of your created instance with [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) method:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames (Object.getPrototypeOf (this))
        .filter(propName => (propName !== 'constructor' && typeof this[propName] === 'function'))
        .forEach(propName => this[propName]());
  }

  bar() {
    console.log('bar');
  }

  baz() {
    console.log('baz');
  }

  // other methods...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare function this way:

```
bar = function() {
  console.log('bar');
};
```

And iterate values of new instance, check for functions and call them:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    Object.values(this).forEach(value => {
      if (typeof value === 'function') {
        value();
      }
    });
  }

  nonFunctionProp = 'nfp';

  bar = function() {
    console.log('bar');
  };

  baz = function() {
    console.log('baz');
  };

  // other methods...
}

new Foo();
```