# How to autoincrement id value using es6 js class notation?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have some problem with classes in es6. Me need auto increment id value each time I'm creating objects. Really don't understand how I can declare variable, assign value to _id and then increment increment variable.

```
    class Rectangle {

        constructor(name,width,height,x,y) {
            if (typeof(name) === 'string' && typeof(width,height,x,y) === 'number' ) {  
                this._id = ?;
                this._name = name;
                this._width = width;
                this._height = height;
                this._x = x;
                this._y = y;

                var div = document.createElement("div");
                document.body.appendChild(div);                 
                div.id = this._id;
                div.style.width = this._width + "px";
                div.style.height = this._height + "px";
                div.style.backgroundColor = "#ededed";
                div.innerHTML = name;


            }

            else  {
                alert("No way!");
                return false;
            }


        }

        moveObj(dx,dy) {
            this._x = this._x + dx
            this._y = this._y + dy
            console.log(this._x,this._y)
            return this;
        }

        getCoords() {
            let x = this._x;
            let y = this._y;
            return [x,y];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add a ID generator as a static method in the Rectangle class:

```
class Rectangle {

  constructor() {
    this._id = Rectangle.incrementId()
  }

  static incrementId() {
    if (!this.latestId) this.latestId = 1
    else this.latestId++
    return this.latestId
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Xerxes! It works but I have some problem that generator creates _id = 1 twice oO

Comment: I found solution:
    static incrementId() {
 if (!this.latestId) {
  this.latestId = 1;
 }
 else this.latestId++;
 return this.latestId;
}

Comment: @Alex I updated my answer to reflect the issue you found. The problem was that returning `i++` instead of `++i` as they set the assignment differently. One after the expression ends and the other before. If my answer helped, consider marking it as correct :)

Comment: Yeah! That was very helpful :) Thank you XerxesNoble!

Answer (score 1):

Using a static variable, which is attached the the class not the instance:

```js
class Rectangle {
    static count = 0; // Stores count of number of instances created
    
    constructor() {
        this.id = ++this.constructor.count;  // Pre increment the count then use it
    }
}

let a = new Rectangle();
console.log(a.id);  // Prints 1
let b = new Rectangle();
console.log(b.id);  // Prints 2
```