# Incrementing object id

Tags: javascript, oop, object, closures, prototype-programming

```
var nextid = 0
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'nextid',
    {value: nextid++, writable: false})
}
var animal1 = new Animal('dog')
var animal2 = new Animal('cat')
```

I wonder if this is a good way compared to using a closure or a factory pattern?

My question is similar to this thread(closure and factory pattern suggested):

[Incrementing object id automatically JS constructor (static method and variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554120/incrementing-object-id-automatically-js-constructor-static-method-and-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those closures and factory patterns in the linked answer exist solely to encapsulate the `nextid` variable in a local scope or factory instance. How you create the animal - as a plain object, as a class instance, or an instance with a readonly property - has nothing to do with this. Each of them are equally good.

Whether you actually need the encapsulation depends on your modularisation approach (e.g. the closure is pointless in a node module) and the uniqueness requirements for ids.

Answer (score 2):

*Ids* shouldn't be generated as part of constructing an object: they should be *assigned* to the object.

Think of an athletic race: do runners choose their dorsal?

```
function Animal() {

}

var idGenerator = new IdGenerator();
var animal = new Animal();
animal.id = idGenerator.generate();
```

Probably you might still be able to generate *ids* in a constructor, but I would try to avoid hard-coding *id generation* injecting an `idGenerator` instead:

```
function Animal(idGenerator) {
    this.id = idGenerator.generate();
}
```

BTW my two cents is you should go with the first approach: runners don't assign dorsals themselves.